# Wrap non-English text in the table cell

Tags: tables, wrap, text

I have long table with many cells almost inside every cell long text. The problem is that non-English text does not wrap correctly.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T2B,T2C]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document} 

\begin{table}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{ | m{1cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | } %перенос слов в клетке частично работает только в первой строке

\hline
%\rowcolor{wordBlue}
\hline
\textbf{Text 1} & \textbf{Some Symbols} & \textbf{Long lines of code} & \textbf{Очень длинные строки, которые почему-то не переносяться корректно} & \textbf{Год} & \textbf{Разнообразные вариации чисел и букв 1234, новый номер 892473124} & \textbf{Text with some new default values.} & \textbf{Базовый текст, в котором могут быть смешаны letters and numbers in different languages + 2} & \textbf{Last column with which I have plenty of troubles and I need to fix} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have found trick that if I do

```
& ~\textbf{Last column with which I have plenty of troubles and I need to fix}
```

it works, but I have indentation that I don't need.

Comment: `~` will cause the indentation, in my point of view

Comment: Yes, but the problem I do not need to have indentation. I need just wrap words correctly. No matter how long they are.

Comment: Is hyphenation supposed to be allowed, or should it be suppressed?

Comment: We can use it, but it didn't work for some reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyphenation of the first word requires a space, even if it is zero.

Here's a way for getting what you want with less input.

I put `T2A` as the last encoding, since it's the one of choice for Russian. Do you really need `T2B` and `T2C`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} % to get landscape orientation
\usepackage[T2B,T2C,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}
  m{#1}
}

\begin{document} 

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ | m{1cm} | *{7}{M{2.5cm} |} >{\hyphenrules{english}}M{2.5cm} | }
\hline
%\rowcolor{wordBlue}
\hline
\bfseries Text 1 & 
  \bfseries Some Symbols & 
  \bfseries Long lines of code & 
  \bfseries Очень длинные строки, которые почему-то не переносяться корректно &
  \bfseries Год &
  \bfseries Разнообразные вариации чисел и букв 1234, новый номер 892473124 &
  \bfseries Text with some new default values. &
  \bfseries Базовый текст, в котором могут быть смешаны
    \foreignlanguage{english}{letters and numbers in different languages} + 2 &
  \bfseries Last column with which I have plenty of troubles and I need to fix \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Add `>{\hyphenrules{english}}` for the columns where only English is used.

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

- Your nine-column table is simply too wide to fit in portrait mode on a normal page, even if the margins are very narrow. Consider typesetting the tabular material in landscape mode, e.g., by loading the `rotating` package and placing the tabular material inside a `sidewaystable` environment.
- Even if the tabular material is set in landscape mode, it will be too wide if you set the widths of columns 2 thru 9 to 2.5cm. I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment and let LaTeX work out the column width that's needed to make the table fit.
- If you want to permit hyphenation of the words, load the `ragged2e` package and modify the column type with a `>{\RaggedRight}` directive. Since the columns will all be quite narrow, it's better to set them in ragged-right mode instead of in "justified" mode.
- Not addressed in the code below, but something to think about: Do you really gain something by bold-facing every single header cell?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T2B,T2C]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{rotating,ragged2e,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document} 

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | p{1cm} | *{8}{L|} }
\hline
\textbf{Text 1} & 
\textbf{Some Symbols} & 
\textbf{Long lines of code} & 
\textbf{Очень длинные строки, которые почему-то не переносяться корректно} & 
\textbf{Год} & 
\textbf{Разнообразные вариации чисел и букв 1234, новый номер 892473124} & 
\textbf{Text with some new default values.} & 
\textbf{Базовый текст, в котором могут быть смешаны 
   letters and numbers in different languages + 2} & 
\textbf{Last column with which I have plenty of troubles and I need to fix} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```